# Prevent Error: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimite PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a small issue with my code. I have a search box which uses multiple variables as a database to search through, everything works fine and displays fine. My issue lies when there is no entry in the textbox, I then get the following error:

> strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimite

Is there a way I can check if the textbox is empty before setting the variables?

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST["searchSub"])) {
    $searchTerm = $_POST["searchTb"];

    $pos1 = strpos($tBody1, $searchTerm);
    $pos2 = strpos($tBody2, $searchTerm);
    $pos3 = strpos($tBody3, $searchTerm);
    $pos4 = strpos($tBody4, $searchTerm);
    $pos5 = strpos($tBody5, $searchTerm);
    $pos6 = strpos($tBody6, $searchTerm);
    $pos7 = strpos($tBody7, $searchTerm);
    $pos8 = strpos($tBody8, $searchTerm);
    $pos9 = strpos($tBody9, $searchTerm);
    $pos10 = strpos($tBody10, $searchTerm);
    $pos11 = strpos($tBody11, $searchTerm);
    $pos12 = strpos($tBody12, $searchTerm);
    $pos13 = strpos($tBody13, $searchTerm);
    $pos14 = strpos($tBody14, $searchTerm);
    $pos15 = strpos($tBody15, $searchTerm);
    $pos16 = strpos($tBody16, $searchTerm);
    $pos17 = strpos($tBody17, $searchTerm);
    $pos18 = strpos($tBody18, $searchTerm);
    $pos19 = strpos($tBody19, $searchTerm);
    $pos20 = strpos($tBody20, $searchTerm);
}
```

Comment: Make sure the relevant field has been entered before attempting to use it `if(isset($_POST["searchSub"], $_POST["searchTb"])) {`

Comment: Use `if (filter_input(INPUT_POST,"searchSub"))` instead of directly doing checks on `$_POST` that way you can also specify filters to sanitize and validate your input.

Comment: @RiggsFolly also thought this would have solved this issue but for some odd reason it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `if(isset($_POST["searchSub"]) && !empty($_POST["searchTb"])) {`

Comment: @apokryfos This method prevented any of the results from being found.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The second method you've provided has done the trick, if you post this as the answer I'll mark it as solved. Thank you.

Comment: Mike Thanks, there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the relevant field has been entered before attempting to use it

```
if(isset($_POST["searchSub"]) && !empty($_POST["searchTb"])) {
    searchTerm = $_POST["searchTb"];

    $pos1 = strpos($tBody1, $searchTerm);
    $pos2 = strpos($tBody2, $searchTerm);
    $pos3 = strpos($tBody3, $searchTerm);
    $pos4 = strpos($tBody4, $searchTerm);
    $pos5 = strpos($tBody5, $searchTerm);
    $pos6 = strpos($tBody6, $searchTerm);
    $pos7 = strpos($tBody7, $searchTerm);
    $pos8 = strpos($tBody8, $searchTerm);
    $pos9 = strpos($tBody9, $searchTerm);
    $pos10 = strpos($tBody10, $searchTerm);
    $pos11 = strpos($tBody11, $searchTerm);
    $pos12 = strpos($tBody12, $searchTerm);
    $pos13 = strpos($tBody13, $searchTerm);
    $pos14 = strpos($tBody14, $searchTerm);
    $pos15 = strpos($tBody15, $searchTerm);
    $pos16 = strpos($tBody16, $searchTerm);
    $pos17 = strpos($tBody17, $searchTerm);
    $pos18 = strpos($tBody18, $searchTerm);
    $pos19 = strpos($tBody19, $searchTerm);
    $pos20 = strpos($tBody20, $searchTerm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use empty() instead of isset()

Answer (score 0):

You should add condition like turnery.

```
if(isset($_POST["searchSub"]) && !empty($_POST["searchTb"])) {
$searchTerm = $_POST["searchTb"];

$pos1 = (tBody1 != "")?strpos($tBody1, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos2 = (tBody2 != "")?strpos($tBody2, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos3 = (tBody3 != "")?strpos($tBody3, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos4 = (tBody4 != "")?strpos($tBody4, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos5 = (tBody5 != "")?strpos($tBody5, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos6 = (tBody6 != "")?strpos($tBody6, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos7 = (tBody7 != "")?strpos($tBody7, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos8 = (tBody8 != "")?strpos($tBody8, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos9 = (tBody9 != "")?strpos($tBody9, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos10 = (tBody10 != "")?strpos($tBody10, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos11 = (tBody11 != "")?strpos($tBody11, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos12 = (tBody12 != "")?strpos($tBody12, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos13 = (tBody13 != "")?strpos($tBody13, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos14 = (tBody14 != "")?strpos($tBody14, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos15 = (tBody15 != "")?strpos($tBody15, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos16 = (tBody16 != "")?strpos($tBody16, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos17 = (tBody17 != "")?strpos($tBody17, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos18 = (tBody18 != "")?strpos($tBody18, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos19 = (tBody19 != "")?strpos($tBody19, $searchTerm):"NULL";
$pos20 = (tBody20 != "")?strpos($tBody20, $searchTerm):"NULL";
```

}

Hope this will is your solution. :)